# Moment return the same value passed to it instead of utc value

Tags: momentjs

Im trying to trasform a date to utc but moment return the same value i use.

for example

`moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

if i use `date = '2022-01-07 11:30:00'` moment return `2022-01-07 11:30:00`

do i have to set the timezone of the value first? why moment return the wrong value? it should return +3 hours that date.

Comment: Why should it return +3 hours? You never indicated the timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define the timezone in which the `date` is, then the offset will be as expected:

Example, using `Europe/Amsterdam` as timezone

```js
const date = '2022-01-07 11:30:00';

const utc = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
              .tz('Europe/Amsterdam')
              .utc()
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(utc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

This will output `2022-01-07 10:30:00` since Amsterdam time is `-1` compared to `UTC`.

---

Small side node, quoting [MomentJS Project Status page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

> **We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done.**
>
> In practice, this means:
>
> - We will not be adding new features or capabilities.
> - We will not be changing Moment's API to be immutable.
> - We will not be addressing tree shaking or bundle size issues.
> - We will not be making any major changes (no version 3).
> - We may choose to not fix bugs or behavioral quirks, especially if they are long-standing known issues.

Answer (score 0):

The data you pass in doesn't have any indication of the timezone it's in, so moment is (I believe) assuming it's in utc already.

In related news, look into using the [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library instead of moment. Moment is getting old...

[Moment github](https://github.com/moment/moment/)

> Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases,
> you should choose a different library.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the same date since you never indicated any timezone

```
var time = moment("2013-08-26 16:55:00") //this creates time in my tz
```

You can set a timezone like this:

```
var time = moment("2013-08-26 16:55:00").tz("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: Also - Consider changing to a lib like https://day.js.org/ which has the same API but it's not deprecated.